# Adding nested git submodule URLs after setting to local paths

Tags: git, github

Is there a way to modify git submodule URLs after setting them initially to local paths after consistent committing on local git submodule? Would this overwrite my other commits?

```
git submodule add url one
```

vs

```
git submodule add localpath two
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the URL of any submodule, you use the command:

`git submodule set-url <newurl>`

You can refer to [this](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-set-url--ltpathgtltnewurlgt) for more information on the topic.

Best.